# What is type for JSX React 'div | p'?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface, react-props

I'm building a custom component and I want to pass the element name as a prop to the component, such as `div` or `p`; an `HTMLElement`

The catch to this is that it must be a block or inline element

```js
export const MyComponent = props => {
  const currentNode = useRef()
  const { tag: Comp } = props
  return <Comp ref={currentNode}>Strawberry Kisses!</Comp>
}
```

As you can see, I'm destructuring the `prop` to get the `tag` value (`Component`) and passing that through as the element.

Currently, the below interface throws an error

```js
Type '{ ref: MutableRefObject<undefined>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)
```

```js
interface MyProps extends React.ClassAttributes<MyComponent> {
  tag: string;
}
```

I need to basically check `if (tag == HTMLElement && tag === JSX.IntrinsicElements) { return 'this is the correct type and allow it' }`

Any help in a direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error has nothing to do with your question, as far as I can tell.

To fix your error you need to do `<Comp ref={currentNode.current}>`

The next error you will probably run into is that you're not passing down the tag prop to your child component.

To actually answer your question, I don't think there is any in-built enum or type of all the names of HTML tags, so you'll have to define it yourself, especially since it seems you want something even more specific.

Comment: I had a look recently and I think the enum theory is right. They use `enum` in the react source files, so I'll have to make a list myself. Thank you, a step in the right direction.